# Log folder having 236 GB Free space

Tags: log, storage, du

I have lost 236 GB because the log folder is taking so much free storage. I used `du` and `sudo du` and the 236 GB are unused.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can start by making clear if the space is used or free, the wording in the question is ambiguous. Are you talking about /var/log ? If so, are there any large files in there ?

Comment: No, it just takes the storage

Comment: Have you deleted any files in /var/log ? I the process that was writing to that file is still running the space are first freed when the possess closes the file or are stopped. Try to reboot your machine, that will stop all processes and free up "locked" disk-space.

Comment: ok thank you I will try

Comment: Is `/var/log` on a separate partition?